# Proof that sum of independent normals is normal using convolutions

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution

Let $X, Y$ be independent standard normal random variables. 
We already know that $X+Y$ is normal with mean 0 and variance 2.
However, I am trying to prove this result in a slightly different way than usual, i.e., using convolutions.

We can address the problem in the following way: the sum of the two variables has a density $h(x)$ given by the convolution product of the densities of the two variables, say $f$ and $g$, so that

$$
h(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-y)g(y)dy.
$$

However, 
$$
f(y) = g(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\exp(-y^2/2).
$$

Hence now the integral becomes:

$$
h(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-(x-y)^2/2)\exp(-y^2/2)dy.
$$

However, I am puzzled here. How should we go on from here? I cannot see how to transform this integral into the integral of a normal r.v of type $N(0,2)$. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $h$ is expected to be the density of a normal r.v. of type $N(0,2)$. What should be the density of an $N(0,2)$? Recall that $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$.

Comment: @ThibautDumont Can you try to write down an answer? I am definitely stuck here.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac12(x-y)^2+\frac12y^2=\left(y-\frac12x\right)^2+\frac14x^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral becomes

$$
h(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-(\color{red}z-y)^2/2)\exp(-y^2/2)dy$$

due to $x=z-y$

$$h(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-(z^2-2zy+y^2)/2)\exp(-y^2/2)dy$$

Focussing on the exponents

$-(y^2/2+y^2/2-zy)-z^2/2$

Completing the square

$-(y^2-zy+z^2/4)+z^2/4-z^2/2$

$-(y-z/2)^2-z^2/4$

$$h(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \exp(-z^2/4)\cdot  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-(y-z/2)^2)dy$$

$$h(x) =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot \exp(-z^2/4)\cdot \underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt \pi}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-(y-z/2)^2)dy}_{=1}$$

To see that the latter expression equals 1 you can substitute $y-z/2$ by $t$.

Comment: Why our limits are from $(-\infty , \infty)$. Suppose we have $X+Y=2$ and we draw the graph and then calculate the area limits of y will be from $(0 , 2-x)$ why is it different from the example I gave ?

Comment: @Daman because that would lead to a conditional density